# Error when opening file in Vim using ConEmu

Tags: windows, powershell, vim, conemu

I am running Vim from Powershell inside ConEmu.

I have my text files set to open using the following command

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74a\vim.exe" --remote-silent "%1"
```

If Vim is already running in ConEmu then when I doubleclink on *.txt file a cmd.exe briefly flashes on screen and the file is opened in the existing Vim process, but I will also get this error message

[image]

Is there a way to stop this error from occuring or simply hide the error message?

Comment: The problem is in current "Default terminal" implementation. Issue was submitted already and fix is pending.

Comment: Awesome! In the mean time I found that if a uncheck 'Force ConEmu as the default terminal...' in Settings > Intergration > Default term then I don't get this error message. The side effect is that if I don't already have vim open in ConEmu then it will be opened in cmd.exe

Comment: [140106](http://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html) build may fix that